# How to pass parameter to WebApi via $resource?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-resource

I'm trying to pass parameter to WebAPI, but something doesn't work. Not sure if I should add :id to the $resource path or not?

My service:

```
dataService.factory('Widgets', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

    var data = $resource('/api/:path', {
        path: '@path'
    }, {
        getWidgets: {
            params: { path: 'widgets' },
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
        },
        getWidget: {
            params: { path: 'widgets' },
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
        },
        getCategories: {
            params: { path: 'widgetCategories' },
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
        },
    });
    return data;
}]);
```

In the controller:

```
Widgets.getWidget({ id: $rootScope.widgetId }).$promise.then(function (result) {
        $scope.widget = result;
    });
```

In ASP.Net Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Widget> Get()
    {
        return _dbContext.Widgets;
    }

    [Route("api/[controller]/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Widget Get(int id)
    {
        return _dbContext.Widgets.Where(w => w.Id == id).FirstOrDefault(); ;
    }
```

Could someone have a look please?

Comment: any error are you getting ?

Comment: no, no error. It direct me to the first Get() method in the controller. And returns the list of widgets and not the single one

Comment: getWidget should be like this - getWidget: {
            params: { path: 'widgets/:id' },
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
        },

Comment: Yep, you use 'path' in resource, but 'id' in controller - but should use  same.

Comment: ok,so now I get error 400 (bad request) and  http://localhost:46899/api/widgets%2F:id?id=31

Comment: What have you got in WebApiConfig.cs? Have you just got a call to MapHttpAttributeRoutes or do you have any manual routing?

Comment: this is ASP.Net 5.0 there is no WebApiConfig.cs. I'm using ui-router for routes

Comment: Ah OK. I'm still wondering if it's an issue with the routing on the server side though. I would add [Route("")] to the Get() method just to be on the safe side, it may be that as it doesn't have a routing attribute ASP.NET is defaulting to the old route table instead.

Comment: same thing mate, error 400

Comment: I just checked the details of the error and I found this: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).